# Detect if Wifi Requires Browser Login

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

My university has an open wifi access point, however it requires you to enter your e-mail before it allows you to use the web. My problem is that the Wifi is stupid in that it seems to drop my connection and force me to enter my e-mail again every 10 minutes.

I wanted to create my own app that I can use to automatically do this step for me, but I cannot seem to find any documentation for a nice and easy way to detect if a Wifi access point has a browser login page. Is there a way in Android to get this information, or is it just to see if my connection to something is always redirected to 1.1.1.1?

Comment: Send an HTTP request to google.com and see what happens.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the "Handling Network Sign-On" section of [the `HttpUrlConnection` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

> Some Wi-Fi networks block Internet access until the user clicks through a sign-on page. Such sign-on pages are typically presented by using HTTP redirects. You can use getURL() to test if your connection has been unexpectedly redirected. This check is not valid until after the response headers have been received, which you can trigger by calling getHeaderFields() or getInputStream().

They have a snippet of sample code there. Whether this will cover your particular WiFi AP, I can't say, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: I implemented this and it works nicely when the redirect changes the hostname, but some don't. For example, this Belkin router leaves whatever you typed in the browser as is, but still displays its own page. urlConnection.getUrl().getHost() returns what it should because of this. Any suggestions in that case? How does Android detect connectivity itself? I.e. the orange vs white Wifi/Data icons.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to validate this ? This approach is error prone. On example is what @Flyview described. 

His approach below is also error prone (see comments on the answer below).

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN: "This approach is error prone" -- that would depend upon circumstance, I guess. By definition, it is not possible to handle Flyview's scenario in general, as a `200 OK` response from the captive portal for the URL is indistinguishable (again, in general) from a `200 OK` response from the real site being hit. With HTTPS, you can check certificates to see whether or not it is the right server, and that should be a more definitive test.

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN Android has its own portal check code that I ended up using myself. It checks the redirect code from a special Google url. Check my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982762/get-wifi-captive-portal-info

Comment: @CommonsWare This is error prone due to the new behavior o Lollipop of routing the data through 3G when WiFi is connected but doesn't have connectivity. So your request will not have a redirect although on the wifi login page (..  because you are not using wifi for them)

Answer (score 3):

Ping an external IP address (like google.com) to see if it responds.

```
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec("ping -c 1 " + "google.com");
        proc.waitFor();     
        int exitCode = proc.exitValue();
        if(exitCode == 0) {
            Log.d("Ping", "Ping successful!";
        } else {
            Log.d("Ping", "Ping unsuccessful.");
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {}
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

The only downside is this would also indicate that a web login is required when there is simply no internet connectivity on the WiFi access point.

@CommonsWare I believe this is a better answer than opening a UrlConnection and checking the host, since the host doesn't always change even when displaying the redirect page. For example, I tested on a Belkin router and it leaves whatever you typed in the browser as is, but still displays its own page. urlConnection.getUrl().getHost() returns what it should because of this.

Comment: This also does not solve the problem as when you connect you may still need to login, but after a while you do login via web page, and when you do you don't receive any event to warn you that something has changed for you to test your connectivity again...

Answer (score 2):

I think @FlyWheel is on the right path, but I would use http://clients1.google.com/generate_204 and if you don't get a 204, you know you are behind a captive portal. You can run this in a loop until you do get a 204 in which case you know you are not behind a captive portal anymore.

@FlyWheel wrote: The only downside is this would also indicate that a web login is required when there is simply no internet connectivity on the WiFi access point.

You can solve this by registering a receiver to android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE. You can check if Wifi is ON and is connected by looking at the Supplicant State of the connection.

Here is a snippet, but I didn't run it:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wm.getConnectionInfo();
SupplicantState suppState = wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();

if (wm.isWifiEnabled()) {
   if (suppState == SupplicantState.COMPLETED){
      // TODO - while loop checking generate_204 (FlyWheels code)Using intent service.
   }
}
```

I can't remember if the SupplicantState is COMPLETED or ASSOCIATED, you will have to check that. You should use an IntentService for checking the generate_204 since broadcast receivers have a short lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code using google's `204` endpoint.

```
 private boolean networkAvailable() {

        ConnectivityManager mManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(mManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = mManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(activeNetwork== null || !activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
                return false;
            }
        }

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://clients1.google.com/generate_204")
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if(response.code() != 204)
                return  false; // meaning it either responded with a captive html page or did a redirection to captive portal.
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Many applications including Google Chrome use http://clients1.google.com/generate_204 to verify that the the connection is not locked under captive portal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might rather be - today at least - that newer Android versions (5.1+?) keep the 3G/4G connection up and running until the wifi login actually leads to a fully functional wifi connection.

I haven't tried it, but maybe with the enum value `CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK` of `NetworkInfo`s [`DetailedState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState.html) one can try to detect such a mode properly?

Comment: The CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK is a transient state and the final state will be CONNECTED even if you are connected to a Captive Wifi.  The way (that worked for me) to check for Captive Wifi is to try to connect to a website and check if you are being redirected to another url.