# Get WiFi captive portal info

Tags: android, wifi, android-5.0-lollipop

Is there a way to access Android's broadcast that the WiFi connection is currently a captive portal (requires web login)? Android seems to do have this built in. If not a broadcast receiver, is there a way to check for the result of the captive portal check? I believe it's using this class, which is hidden from the API:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/net/CaptivePortalTracker.java

Prior to 4.2, it was probably using:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiWatchdogStateMachine.java

**Background:**

I had been using my own method to detect whether WiFi likely required a login. I would wait for a WiFi connected state, then ping a site and make sure there was a response. This seemed to work great in most cases. Another strategy is to do a HttpRequest and check for a redirect or the response body you receive back, similar to Android's strategy in the classes listed above.

**However, new to Lollipop** is that the mobile data connection is used when WiFi does not have connectivity. This means my ping method will still return results, and that a redirect would not happen, as the request would be routed over the mobile data.

Is there a way to get Android's current status of a WiFi captive portal? If not, can we make sure a request goes over WiFi even when there's no connectivity as seen by Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use the new `ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork` API to force your app to communicate over the captive portal. See https://github.com/pawitp/muwifi-autologin/commit/f045fe36f1fd98a106ea652e2d56f7ddfc871760 for an example.

Complete code added:

```
final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (Network net : cm.getAllNetworks()) {
    if (cm.getNetworkInfo(net).getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        Utils.logDebug(TAG, "Seting process network to " + net);  
        /*Since API 23 ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(net); 
        is deprecated, use: */
        cm.bindProcessToNetwork(net);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes after posting this that's what I have been trying to do. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work too well. When I requestNetwork on a captive portal WiFi network, the WiFi disappears from the status bar (and comes back in a few seconds). I will keep trying to see if I can make it work.

Comment: Use cm.getAllNetworks() and ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork. Do not use requestNetwork.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Found the correct network and set it with setProcessDefaultNetwork (code added to your answer). I was trying to use requestNetwork to get a network, but cm.getAllNetworks() helped me find it instead.